# Convert string to date, including NaNs

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code, which has worked fine, but I think I have a null value that I'm attempting to convert to a date:

```
df['date_field'] = df['date_field'].str.replace("\"","", case=False).astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

I get the error: "Error parsing datetime string "nan" at position 0 "

Is there a way to just put NaN in this field or a dummy date when this error is encountered?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `pd.to_datetime` rather than `astype`, this should gracefully insert a `NaN` if it can't parse the value into a date.